# Callback option in Shraepoint 2010 OpenPopUpPageWithTitle

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I called OpenPopUpPageWithTitle method to pop open a new list item form from a simple HTML button.  It did everything I wanted except the callback. I tried to call a custom JS function (simply a dialog box with some message) from the parent page after the popup page closes.  Where should I place (or inject) the custom JS function so the callback can find it?  Please note I only have Sharepoint Designer to work with.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function should be defined in the same scope in which you're invoking `OpenPopUpPageWithTitle()`.

```
(function(){

    // do stuff

    // invoke your modal dialog
    OpenPopUpPageWithTitle("http://www.bing.com",myCallBack,500,300,"My Dialog");

    // do other stuff

    // define the call back function within the same scope:
    function myCallBack(){
        alert("Success!");
    }

})();
```

or you can use an in-line anonymous function:

```
OpenPopUpPageWithTitle("http://www.bing.com",
    function(){
        alert("Success!");
    },500,300,"My Dialog");
```

Comment: Many thanks.  On the first option, if this is in Sharepoint Designer, how can I achieve that?  Would you provide an example?

Comment: @1001b Is this on a web part page? In SP2010, the easiest way to get JavaScript onto the page and execute it is to put the code within `<script>` tags in a text file, then pull that into a content editor web part (using the "Content Link" property in the web part properties). This can be done in the browser, no SharePoint Designer required.

Comment: It is the default.aspx page.  A script tag workaround should work for me.  But it would be great if I can directly insert it using code mode in Sharepoint Designer editor.